# Hive encrypted box key storage in Flutter secure_storage null safety issue

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

Need some help with this issue, I have tried everything and really have no clue how to resolve this.

I'm applying code as per the Hive [documentation](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/advanced/encrypted_box) for encrypted storage and key storage with secure_storage. I have chosen to use dart 2.12 with null safety but this seems impossible. I really can't even tell where the real issue is here.

```
final FlutterSecureStorage secureStorage = const FlutterSecureStorage();
    var containsEncryptionKey = await secureStorage.containsKey(key: 'key');
    if (!containsEncryptionKey) {
      var key = Hive.generateSecureKey();
      await secureStorage.write(key: 'key', value: base64UrlEncode(key));
    }
    var encryptionKey = base64Url.decode(await secureStorage.read(key: 'key'));
    var encryptedBox =
        await Hive.openBox<Sale>(kSalesBox, encryptionCipher: HiveAesCipher(encryptionKey));
```

The issue above is highlighted as: `await secureStorage.read(key: 'key')`

I have tried everything and I can't understand what the IDE wants, the message does not make sense in this application.

The error message:

```
Decrypts and returns the value for the given [key] or null if [key] is not in the storage.

[key] shouldn't be null. [iOptions] optional iOS options [aOptions] optional Android options [lOptions] optional Linux options Can throw a [PlatformException].

The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
```

But the key won't be null! Thats what the "if" check is for...

Answer (score 1):

Solved by random guess...

Applied brackets to error highlight and null assertion operator "!" as follows:

`var encryptionKey = base64Url.decode((await secureStorage.read(key: 'key'))!);`

Comment: The `!` is called [null-assertion-operator](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator) and it does not force a null check, instead you are telling the compiler that you are 100% sure, that the result is never null.

Answer (score 0):

For me start working after I added `aOptions: _getAndroidOptions()` to the
`secureStorage.containsKey` like this:

```
await secureStorage.containsKey(key: 'encryptionKey',aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
```

and then I uninstall the app from the emulator and build and run again.

Also the same with `secureStorage.read(key: 'encryptionKey',aOptions`:

```
_getAndroidOptions()) and secureStorage.write(key: 'encryptionKey',aOptions: _getAndroidOptions())
```